# Getting the AzureB2C id provider object id

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I don't quite understand how to get the ObjectId from my claims in azureB2C.
I have tried this code:

```
string theId = User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

I think it might be working. But to be honest I am not sure if this is the right Value. Also, if it is, surely there must be a better/simpler way to do it. Or at least one that is clearer somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ASP.NET web app, you can use:

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
```

See [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/Controllers/TasksController.cs) for an example of this.

For an ASP.NET web API, you can use:

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value
```

See [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskService/Controllers/TasksController.cs) for an example of this.